# SMTP Mail Failures to a certain domain

Tags: email, smtp

Do the SMTP logs on a server (Windows 2003) only show logs of mail that were sent successfully?

We are getting bounce backs when sending mail to a particular domain:

```
 The connection was dropped by the remote host.
```

It looks like a problem on the receiving server, but we dont have much information to provide them. We can send to hotmail, gmail, yahoo etc OK.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, there is a spam filter in front of the receiving mail server for this domain, and this spam filter thinks your mail server is sending spam, so it's closing the connection from your mail server.  One way to test this is to simulate sending a message to this mail server by opening a command prompt on your mail server, and use telnet to connect to the receiving mail server on port 25, and proceed with the process of sending a message just as a mail server would.  This way, you'll be able to see how the receiving mail server responds after each step.  Follow the instructions in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119 to see how this is done.

Comment: This was pretty much it. The server sending the mail had been blacklisted by McAfee which was running on the receiving firewall.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the sending server was blacklisted by McAfee, that was running on the receiving servers firewall.

For those that may have the problem in the future you can check if your server is blacklisted with McAfee here:

http://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/ip/spam-senders.aspx

After entering your server IP, you should see a link Threat Feedback. Use this to email McAfee.

I was able to send McAfee an email with an explanation, they then removed our server from the blacklist.